# Convert chess grid (A1, B2, D5, etc.) to tuple coordinates (e.g. (0,0), (1,1) in Python

Tags: python

I need to convert chess grid to tuple coordinates.

For A1 = (0,0), A2 = (0,1), D5 = (3, 4)

Managed to solve it:)

```
action = K3
col, row = action
row = int(row)
col = ALPHABETS.index(col)
return (row, col)
```

Comment: And what did you do to achieve that? Or at least try?

Comment: Please clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `A1` is a string:

```
C = "A1"
a = ord(C[0]) - ord('A')
b = ord(C[1]) - ord('1')

T = (a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ord('A')` is 65, `ord('B')` is 66 and so on, so we can define a function like this:

```
def to_tuple(square):
    return (ord(square[0]) - 65, int(square[1]) - 1)
```

Test:

```
print(to_tuple('A1'), to_tuple('D5'), to_tuple('H8'), sep='\n')
```

```
(0, 0)
(3, 4)
(7, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Arne 's answer, you can store the variable `A1 = to_tuple(A1)`.

You are storing the function's value, or return value(written in front of the return statement: in this case it is `(ord(square[0]) - 65, int(square[1]) - 1)`) in the variable `A1`.

Hope this helps