# how do i reference the index of a 2-d array and assign it to variables

Tags: python

I'm making a chess program and am wondering how I can refference the index of a 2-d array of coordinates and assign that index to x and y variables in order for me to move pieces and save writing a heap of elif statements.

```
self.coor =  [['a8','b8','c8','d8','e8','f8','g8','h8'],
                      ['a7','b7','c7','d7','e7','f7','g7','h7'],
                      ['a6','b6','c6','d6','e6','f6','g6','h6'],
                      ['a5','b5','c5','d5','e5','f5','g5','h5'],
                      ['a4','b4','c4','d4','e4','f4','g4','h4'],
                      ['a3','b3','c3','d3','e3','f3','g3','h3'],
                      ['a2','b2','c2','d2','e2','f2','g2','h2'],
                      ['a1','b1','c1','d1''e1','f1','g1','h1']]

def movePiece():
    moveFrom = input("From:")
```

Comment: You could use a nested dict, instead of a nested list. Or a dict with `(x, y)` tuples as keys.

Comment: You have a typo between 'd1' and 'e1'. That will make it a single string 'd1e1' by implicit string concatenation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert chess grid (A1, B2, D5, etc.) to tuple coordinates (e.g. (0,0), (1,1) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60922366/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that converts a coordinate string (e.g. 'f4') to a tuple containing the indexes to access this element in the array.

```py
def str2idx(s: str) -> tuple[int, int]:
    idx1 = 8 - int(s[1])
    idx2 = ord(s[0]) - ord('a')
    return (idx1, idx2)

print(str2idx('a8'))  # (0, 0)
print(str2idx('c2'))  # (6, 2)
print(str2idx('e6'))  # (2, 4)
print(str2idx('h1'))  # (7, 7)
```